# Formula for working out an ID number by given set of coordinates

Tags: sequences-and-series, modular-arithmetic

I'm designing an online game and having a bit of a mental block coding the navigation system. It's designed on a 2 dimensional grid, each cell has an ID 0...n, n being the total number of cells in the grid.

What I need to be able to do is figure out the ID number based on the given X & Y coordinates. So in the example below, I'd expect to get the value 25 when entering the co-ordinates 4x2 (0 based index on the co-ordinates)

Bear in mind that the grid could be any given height and width, in this case 5 and 10 respectively.

$$
\begin{array}{r}
 1 &  2 &  3 &  4 &  5 &  6 &  7 &  8 &  9 & 10 \\
11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 \\
21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 & 30 \\
31 & 32 & 33 & 34 & 35 & 36 & 37 & 38 & 39 & 40 \\
41 & 42 & 43 & 44 & 45 & 46 & 47 & 48 & 49 & 50
\end{array}
$$

I'm sure this is going to be an embarrassingly simple problem, thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What you're talking about is modular arithmetic, I think.   Could you give another example where the width $\neq 10$?  I'm also assuming you'd like to *calculate* this value, as opposed to retrieving it.

Comment: Hi vermiculus, thanks for that I'll update the tags. So the grid could be 10x10, 15x10, 5x5 etc. there's no real restriction on the dimensions.
Yep that's right - I'd like to calculate the ID without having to make a database or cache hit to retrieve the number.

Comment: No, I meant how would the numbers roll out?  I'm assuming $$\begin{array}&1&2&3&4&5&6\\7&8&9&10&11&12\end{array}$$ would be another example?

Comment: Yep that's right, ill have a look at your function below thanks

Comment: Do you want to start counting with $0$ or with $1$? (This refers both to the block id and to the x/y coordinates an dI just wonder because your post is contradictory about that)

Comment: In the actual function it's 0-based as are the coordinates, not sure why I changed it here tbh as it's ended up making it more confusing rather than less!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

$$f(x,y,w)=(x \mod w) + yw$$

(where $x \mod w$ is often `x % w`)

---

Why does this work?  Consider this arrangement of the natural numbers $\mathbb{N} = \{0,1,2,3,\dots\}$:

$$(y\cdot w)_{y \in \mathbb{N}}\Bigg\{
\overbrace{
\begin{array}{r}
 0 &  1 &  2 &  3 &  4 &  5 &  6 &  7 \\
 8 &  9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15\\
16 & 17 & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots
\end{array}}^{w=8}
$$

$w$ here is your **modulus**.
What is a modulus, you say?
A modulus is a number by which you divide to obtain a remainder.

Note that for any number $x \in \mathbb{N}$,
  you can find the remainder of $\frac{x}{w}$ by
  locating it in the array and looking at the very top column.
This is the idea of the modulus,
and the operation done by `x % w` in C-like languages.

Thus, the operation $(x\mod w)$ finds the column in which $x$ is in this modulus, and $y \cdot w$ skips to the row.  Thus, $(x\mod w) + yw$ skips to the row and column to find your index.  :-)

Comment: Hey thanks for this it seems to work, would you mind explaining how? :-)

Comment: I can certainly try.

Comment: @managedheap84 See the edit.